# How do I access another prototype object after data binding using 'with' in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs and have an object like this:

```
var home = function(){
    this.title = 'Home',
    this.vm = {
        names: ko.observableArray(),
        metadata: {
            startDate: ko.observableArray()
        }
    }
};

home.prototype.create = function(){
   alert('creating');
};

home.prototype.addNewPerson = function(){
    alert(this);
    this.create();
};

return home;
```

Then in my HTML, I use the `with` binding:

```
<div data-bind='with: vm.metadata'>
    <input data-bind='value: startDate' />
    <button data-bind='click: $parent.addNewPerson />
</div>
```

- this isn't my exact code, but a simplified version

When the user clicks on the button in this situation, `this` will be my metadata object. So I'll get an undefined error, because metadata doesn't have a create method.

If I don't use the `with` binding and instead bind like this:
`<input data-bind='value: vm.metdatadata().startDate'/>`

Then when the user clicks, I get my entire object, and I can call `this.create();`

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. If it is, how can I access my main module in the addNewPerson method while still using the with binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of the `click` binding: `this` will be set the current "item" so in your case the `metadata` object.

There are multiple ways to solve this:

You can use [`bind` function](https://www.google.hu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind&ei=65VJUsrQK87GswbVgoCoBg&usg=AFQjCNEwgwCdmP5hyztvAjagyRtlOfNHyA&sig2=ZG1cYiUf2NAmyr7ay4CfDQ&bvm=bv.53217764,d.Yms) (Knockout comes with its own version if your browser does not nattily supports it) to fix the value of `this` to your parent object in your view:

```
<div data-bind='with: vm.metadata'>
    <input data-bind='value: startDate' />
    <button data-bind='click: $parent.addNewPerson.bind($parent) />
</div>
```

Or you can do the same in your viewmodel level (the syntax looks a little bit funny because of the usage of the prototype):

```
var home = function(){
    this.title = 'Home',
    this.vm = {
        names: ko.observableArray(),
        metadata: {
            startDate: ko.observableArray()
        }
    }
    this.addNewPerson = this.addNewPerson.bind(this);
};


home.prototype.addNewPerson = function(){
    alert(this);
    this.create();
};
```

Or you can use the event delegation pattern described in the article: [Revisting Event Delegation in Knockout.js](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/11/revisit-event-delegation-in-knockout-js.html)

You can also check out Ryan Niemeyer's nice video: [devLink 2013 - Knockout.js Tips and Tricks](http://vimeo.com/73627803) where the second tip is about Controlling “this”